# Suppose G is finite, Show G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is finite, let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be the conjugacy classes in $G$ and they are distinct. how do I show that if $a_ib_j = b_ja_i$ where $a_i$ is in $A_i$ and $b_j$ is in $A_j$, then $G$ is abelian

Thanks

Comment: Take two elements in $G$ .if they belong to the same class then they commute.if not try to see what happens if $a\in A_i ,\: b\in A_j$

Comment: suppose b and c are both in Ai, then bab^-1cac^-1 = cac^-1bab^-1, is this right? but I can't get they are commute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a nice [blog post](http://dakecht.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/reps-of-conjugacy-classes-pairwise-commute-g-is-abelian-11/) that discusses this problem. I will add the screenshot here just in case the link becomes broken (and make this community-wiki answer).

[image]

Comment: I am wondering why the order of G is greater than r if G is non ablelian

Comment: @user132177 if the order of G was equal to $r$, then $G=Z$ and so G would be abelian.